From topology to biomolecular topology
Recently I came across an article about biomolecular topology. I want to know how can a topologist (who has no prior knowledge in biology) do research in biomolecular topology?
Like what courses in biology should a topologist complete to be able to carry out research in biomolecular topology?
(Biomolecular Topology: Modelling and Analysis by Liu, Xia, Wu, Yau & Wei, Acta Mathematica 2022)

Do you have that reference available via a link?

Yes, you can find it at https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s10114-022-2326-5.pdf

Nowadays it is not uncommon for physicists, mathematicians, computer scientists and others to switch to computational biology/bioinformatics and make important contributions. Topology may be relevant for protein/RNA structures or analyzing philogenetic trees. It requires learning some biology - but mostly what is relevant to your work - you are not going to compete on the same ground with the biologists who studied it from undergrad, rather collaborate with them.

You're unlikely to find a better source than the article you read (https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s10114-022-2326-5.pdf) to start piecing together a potential curriculum.
"Biomolecular topology" is to my knowledge an entirely new phrase that the article you linked is trying to introduce. On the math side, you could pick up some topological data analysis and perhaps knot theory. On the chemistry side, much (though not all) of the activity that the review surveys has been conducted by the review's authors, especially in using topological summaries to improve drug discovery pipelines.
So to summarize, there are two options I recommend if you want to study this stuff:

Chase references in the survey to the constituent papers and just start reading. Continue chasing until you have a list of topics in chemistry you want to know.

You could also just email the corresponding authors on the survey to see if they recommend any chemistry textbooks. There's always some risk they're too busy to respond, but otherwise they're really some of the only people in the world worth asking. The last author hires postdocs frequently who do topological data analysis, so you could also apply to those.


